# Escaping characters in a for loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Alright, so let's say we have a file called start.cmd

```
@echo off

set value=1
for /D %%a in (%*) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

start.cmd is called by

> start.cmd ^%value^% ^%anothervalue^%

The for loop would, of course, take %1, and %2, and so forth.

My question is:

**EDIT: How can I escape a value within another value?**

Comment: Perhaps you find that you have to use ^ because value and anothervalue are not defined????

Comment: Their both defined, that's why it was replaced with 1, hence it was defined.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you get from execution and what should you get?

Comment: Edited question, as it wasn't what I was ultimately looking for.

Comment: Let's try this one more time... What WERE you looking for?  What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I'm trying too have %value% too printed as just %value%, without it being assigned the value it currently has [1].

Answer (score 1):

I make a guess:

You want to expand the variables just in the for loop, not before.

With your case you only need to add a `CALL`, as it starts the parser a second time, so it can expand the `%value%` before it echo it.

```
@echo off

set value=1
for /D %%a in (%*) do (
    call echo %%a
)
```

But better is to use delayed expansion here

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set value=1
for /D %%a in (%*) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

Then you can start your batch with

```
start.cmd !value! !anothervalue!
```

This works as delayed expansion is done after the percent expansion by the parser, so `%*` is expanded to `!value! !anothervalue!` and then it's expanded to `1 xyz`